# Counting the number of Rubik's cube states in which k = 0 to 4 of the faces are "solved"

Tags: co.combinatorics

Imagine an $n \times n \times n$ Rubik's cube, where we can transition the state of the cube using Singmaster moves under either the face- or quarter-turn metrics.  We call a face of this cube "solved" if all of the symbols on the face are of the same color (there are six total colors).

How many total cube states are there when $k = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}$ of the cube faces are solved, and what "distribution" are these states drawn from?  Namely, what is the probability that they contain the fully solved state of the cube?  Is this probability what one would expect for a uniform random sampling from the set of all possible cube states?

Note: This is (hopefully) a simplification of an earlier question asking for the probability that a greedy algorithm solves a Rubik's cube, where once a face is solved, the algorithm cannot backtrack and perturb the face (though rotations of the face are allowed).

Note 2: I know there are only going to be a small number of possible cube states when we freeze a face. Exact counts would be fantastic, but my goal here is to understand what distribution they are being drawn from.

Comment: I can do the cases $k=6$ and $k=5$...!

Comment: @Greg Martin :)

Comment: If you really fix one face then it will be hard to solve the cube :)

Comment: @Francois Brunault I'm looking to make a statement of just how frequently you can solve the cube when you fix one or more faces.  The answer, no doubt, will be "very infrequently".

Comment: There are two interpretations. (1) For $k$ colours, there are $k$ monochromatic faces of the cube.  (2) The 9 squares of each of the $k$ colours are in exactly the positions they hold in some complete solution.

Version (2) is a point-wise stabiliser problem that any group package should be able to answer.  Version (1) is a bit tricker (unless it can be proved that it is really the same).

Comment: @Brendan McKay Version (1) is what I had in mind.  I don't want to condition on the cells being in the correct positions for a solved cube.  

Comment: @FloatingForest : my point is that if you are not allowed to perturb a face, then you have only 2 possible moves and thus only 16 possible states... how can you possibly solve the cube?

Comment: @Francois Brunault Well, I'm allowing rotations of the face, so 4^3 = 64 states are possible once we fix one face, but you're absolutely right.  What I'm trying to understand is, what is the probability that the solved cube is one of those states?  Or are those states more or less a random sample of all possible cube states?

Comment: @FloatingForest. Thanks for the clarification (I still don't get why 4^3, but nevermind). (Also, technically speaking this procedure should not be called an algorithm, since it only solves the cube with very small probability.)

Comment: 4 faces solved  means all the corner cubes are in proper position, as are some of the edge cubes.  Enumerating the remaining cases should be easily done.
Three faces should be doable after the case of four faces.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.12.20 

Comment: If my arithmetic holds up, I count 8 states total for both arrangments of 4 faces. (No edge flips or corner twists to worry about.) Gerhard "Or Is It 7.999 States?" Paseman, 2012.12.20

Comment: This is for n=3 of course.  N=4 is more challenging.  Gerhard "Not Ready For Higher Orders" Paseman, 2012.12.20

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman Do you think those cube states are random samples of all possible cube states, or somehow biased?

Comment: Depends on possible.  If you get to remove and flip cubelets or color stickers, the number of possiblities increases at a reasonably computable proportion.  My numbers were based on feasible configurations of the order 3 cube, which is (roughly) half the number of total configurations assuming you have a screwdriver to disassemble and reassemble the order 3 cube.  I am not sure about the exacto knife (sticker swapping) version.  Gerhard "Name More Math After Tools" Paseman, 2012.12.20

Comment: To answer your comment, solvable states are a subset (and biased in terms of a certain invariant on permutations) of all states of a permuted (by screwdriver) cube.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.12.20